# nodejs env setting for docker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker

i wanna use id, token for env setting for security
so in docker-compose.yml i put below code but

```
  frontend:
build:
  context: frontend
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
stdin_open: true
volumes:
  - './frontend:/app:cached'
  - './frontend/node_modules:/app/node_modules:cached'
environment:
  - AUTH_TOKEN=token
  - ACCOUNT_SID=account
  - NODE_ENV=development
```

I set AUTH_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_SID in docker-compose.yml

but when i console.log(process.env.AUTH_TOKEN), it is 'undefined' in my react-app
how can i properly set this env?

thank you

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: umm i used 'https://github.com/Buuntu/fastapi-react'

Comment: process.env is a node thing. Once your app is built, you cannot access that. You app will run in the users browser. So you can use them only for building the app.

Comment: I cannot find a stackoverflow question that answers yours, but the answer will almost certainly involve adding the `dotenv` package to your react project

Comment: @evolutionxbox no thats not true.

Comment: @TheFool ok. May you please elaborate on that? --- I have used `process.env` variables in many react front-end projects using `dotenv` and also create-react-app.

Comment: environent variables are a general thing. Independent from any dontenv package you may install. process.env can just access them. `dotenv` package you mention has the purpose of taking a `.env` file and loading those into the environment. Thats not the case here. In this case the env vars are already properly set in the enviroment.

Comment: You use them to build, you can set a variable from those which will be accesible. But you cannot call process.env in your browser. Final built app will run in the users browser, so how could it access env variables in YOUR system?

Comment: to inject envrionment variable like that into your react app, you need to prefix your environment variables like so: `REACT_APP_`, so you should do `REACT_APP_AUTH_TOKEN`, then it will be available as same name in your build (assuming you build your react app in the dockerfile)

Comment: There are hacks with entrypoint around this. But simply using proccess.env from frontend code is not possible.

Comment: @TheFool May you consider converting your comments into an answer? You've explained it pretty well.

Comment: yes. i already used 'dotenv' but it didnt work. i think docker cannot sarch .env in same folders.

Comment: @LCW `dotenv` doesn't enable using `process.env` in the browser. It only enables using environment variables at build time using a node process.

Comment: thanks for many replies. and how can i protect my secret for deploy? now i just made another export dev.ts including upper variables and import. and i exclude dev.ts by .gitignore. may i know any more improved way?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ah now i can understand

Comment: there is one more question.. when i console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV). it works.. 'development' what is different of two things.

Comment: Are you doing this in your browser or from a process spawned by node?

Comment: @TheFoll im doing this in my browser